# EJB module can't reach JPA entities

Tags: maven, jpa, ejb, wildfly, ear

I have a Maven project with 4 modules: JPA module with persistence.xml, EJB module, Webapp module and and EAR module.

I use the EJB module to persist entities in the database. Now when I try to use any entity from the JPA module, I get the following error in Wildfly 9:

```
    22:42:59,298 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MusicEJB.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MusicEJB.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "MusicEJB.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class authentication.AuthEJB with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.MusicEJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
    ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: entity/User
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: entity.User from [Module "deployment.MusicEJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    ... 15 more
```

here is my persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="MusicProjectPersistence" transaction-type="JTA">    
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/postgresDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>entity.User</class>
        <class>entity.MusicFile</class>
        <class>entity.Playlist</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/musicdb" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="music" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="music" />

            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have the the JPA module in my EJB pom.xml

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: JAR file representing JPA module must end up in EAR's `/lib` folder. Is this confirmed when you let maven produce a EAR file and then inspect its contents? Exception suggests it's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your EJB cant  find your entity classes because If you opened your ear file after the build you will find that your JPA module is sitting next to the EJB module and not in the lib folder. The solution is quite simple. Just add your JPA module as dependency in the POM of your ear module. This way, your JPA module will be a jar in the lib folder of your ear, then your EJB and Web modules can find the JPA enitites in their class path. After you add the dependency, build your project and chek in the ear lib folder to assure that your JPA module is their as a jar.

Answer (score 0):

When using a WildFly, you usually don't have the necessity to use EAR packaging, but instead put everything into a WAR, resulting in not having different classloaders, which might solve the problem for you.

Check out [Adam Bien's example](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_ee_6_ejb_31) for a maven-based project using WAR packaging - it does not use a JPA module, but I guess you'll get the idea.